# Old Networking rather than New Networking

Tags: networking

I had an old distro of Raspbian installed and have for a while, and I used to be able to set up networking, manually configure /etc/network/interfaces.

I have found the network manager has changed in the most recent version of raspbian (downloaded on the day of this post) and now uses something called dhcpcd. Not keen on this as the interface names and configuration methods have changed: Is there any way to go back to the old network stuff?

I'm also having an issue with raspi-config. It simply doesn't work when I try to turn on Predictable Interface Names, even after a reboot. EDIT: I'd call the old interface names predictable, however the Pi apparently calls the new ones predictable. Turning this option off brought back the old interface names.

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8) 
# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf' 
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

Practically empty.

`/etc/network/interfaces.d` as a directory is also empty.

Comment: `dhcpcd` is the `DHCP client daemon` which retrieves a (dynamic - that's the D in DHCP) IP address from the DHCP server for your Pi. Please post your `/etc/network/interfaces` - there may be some dynamic configuration inside.

Comment: In future, please edit additional info into the question, do not post it in comments (although using a comment to indicate the information "has been added above" is fine).  WRT "practically empty", the last line provides a clue about this (it will source any files in that directory, although there are not necessarily any, but if there are, you should post those too).

Comment: @goldilocks Added details about `source-directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this disable the **DHCP client daemon** and switch to standard **Debian networking**:

```
sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd
sudo systemctl enable networking
```

See [How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697) which details how to set Static IP Address using Debian networking. **NOTE** I do not recommend using a Static IP Address.

[How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) explains Predictable Network Interface Names and other networking configuration.

**NOTE** I do not recommend using Debian networking - `dhcpcd` is more reliable - you just need to learn to use it. There are even more changes since Wheezy due to `systemd` and `Device Tree` you will have to learn.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! I must ask though - why do you recommend against setting a static IP address?

Comment: @DevelopedLogic I do not want to start a flame war. Most of the people who try don't understanding networking and get it wrong. Also there is no need if you know how to use your computer. It seems to be a Pi disease - Windows and Mac users seem to get along without! When I first built a network ~1980 there was little choice - which is why DHCP was invented.

Comment: I only wondered as I split my network between static and DHCP, mainly as I run a few servers including a local DNS server.